# Display automatically shuts off while watching videos

Tags: windows, video, power-management

Whenever I'm watching a video streamed over the web, my display will *auto-off* due to not touching the mouse or keyboard.

How can I configure the computer to not timeout like this while watching a video?

Comment: Are these flash videos?  And how long before the display shuts from no interaction?

Comment: Yea flash vids on the web. my computer is set to display-off in 10 minutes. I like it that way. However I hate it when it's doing it when i'm watching videos.